# what is gio-launch-desktop and why does Thunderbird use it to open links in default browser

Tags: desktop-environment, browser, thunderbird

In my Thunderbird preferences, I have set chromium as default browser:

```
network.protocol-handler.app.https      /usr/bin/chromium
network.protocol-handler.app.http       /usr/bin/chromium
```

But when I click on a link in email, instead of opening the URL in chromium, `Thunderbird` starts a program `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/gio-launch-desktop`.

What is `gio-launch-desktop`, and what is its role and usefulness when opening URL ?

Is it possible to tell Thunderbird to start chromium directly ?

I am using `RBAC` security control and this whole cascade makes it difficult to create simple rules. This situation where scripts are calling other scripts, calling other scripts in endless cascade (same as with `xdg-open`) seems unnecessarily over-complicated.

Comment: Which distro and version are you using? How did you install Thunderbird?

Comment: @KGIII - Debian Buster, and I installed Thunderbird as debian package. However, i don't think the problem I am having is debian-specific.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question was mostly to eliminate it being an Ubuntu snap issue and to make sure the specific info is here just in case it is distro specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gio-launch-desktop` is part of GNOME's GLib low-level core library. It is launched in the Glib file `gdesktopappinfo.c` by the function `g_desktop_app_info_launch_uris_with_spawn` which is apparently called when the system receives a request to launch an application, e.g. from a function within Thunderbird. It sets `GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID` environment variable before executing an application, as noted in [GNOME/glib commit 742efe6](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/commit/742efe6232aba81c2c52c229c900a57ec2afedfd).

It seems that the GLib maintainers thought the use of `gio-launch-desktop` overly complicated as well. In GLib releases after Feb 14, 2020, `gio-launch-desktop` no longer exists, having been replaced by use of `sh`, as indicated in [GNOME/glib commit 8f7faac](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/commit/8f7faac10fe71c8d8bd5acefa894c4ffa03a2ad4).

As Thunderbird clearly causes the underlying system to start Chromium rather than starting it directly (most likely because it doesn't know what browser is the default browser), it seems clear that it's not possible to tell it to do otherwise without digging into and rewriting its source code.